# How do I transform this JSON data using JQ to extract each nested array element to the top level in turn?

Tags: json, jq, flatten

Given input of the form

```
[
    {"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 1}, {"c": 2}]}, 
    {"a": 2, "b": [{"c": 4}, {"c": 5}]}
]
```

I'm trying to transform to look like:

```
[
    {"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 1}],
    {"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 2}],
    {"a": 2, "b": [{"c": 3}],
    {"a": 2, "b": [{"c": 4}]
]
```

I have `[map(.b) ] | flatten`, however any further operation using the parent context does not seems to be possible. I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution that makes no mention of any keys besides "b":

```
map(. + (.b[] | {b: [.]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this filter:

```
jq 'map({a,"b":.b[]|[.]})' file
```

It updates the content of `b` with each value of `c` separately.